# Const on struct

Tags: c, constants

What is the difference between doing the following three `const` ways of defining a struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const typedef struct Person1 {
    char*  name;
    int    id;
} Person1;

typedef struct Person2 {
    const char*  name;
    const int    id;
} Person2;

const typedef struct Person3 {
    const char*  name;
    const int    id;
} Person3;

void main(void) {
    Person1 p1 = {"John", 1};
    Person2 p2 = {"John", 1};
    Person3 p3 = {"John", 1};
    printf("%s %s %s", p1.name, p2.name, p3.name);

}
```

What particular guarantees do each give? Here is an example of compiler output: https://godbolt.org/z/MWdcaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types `Person1` and `Person3` are aliases for `const struct Person1` and `const struct Person3`.  That means that any variable of type `Person1` or `Person3` cannot be modified (and by extension any of their fields) after initialization.  However, variables of type `struct Person1` or `sturct Person3` *can* be modified provided they are not declared with the `const` qualifier.

Instances of `Person2` can be modified.  In particular, `name` can be modified because it is not `const` even though what it points to is.  The `id` field however *cannot* be modified for *any* instance of `Person2` (and `struct Person2`) because it is `const`.  The same applies to `struct Person3`.

Comment: what do you mean by "does nothing"? If you look at the compiler output it puts all items in `.rodata` for the first and third ones, but not the second one, so it seems to modify where the data is stored by the OS: https://gyazo.com/6d6dddb0d1fd419d199753f0e815d85e

Comment: @David542 `const` in front of the type name is useless, in fact the compiler will warn you of that.  Your comment also seems to suggest that the code you posted is not the code you're testing with.

Comment: I see, updated the question so both code and compiler explorer are the same.

Comment: would someone ever want to do: `const typedef const struct Person4` ?

Comment: @David542 Multiple `const` qualifiers like that are redundant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The first part of the answer applied to OP's original code which had a typedef without a type name.  I've removed that to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ah, okay, And does the comment “`const` in front of the type name is useless”? Also refer to that old code? Because `const typedef int foo;` does define `foo` to be the `const int` type, and the warning in the original code would be for the missing declarator, not for the location of `const`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, it was originally `const typedef struct Person1 { ... };`